# Type and object with "key" property

Tags: typescript

I have following source code and I think what is/could be the purpose of the following syntax:

```
type CatalogCategoryWithKey = CatalogCategory & { key: string };
```

Anybody can link some information, when and why programmer will need such kind of syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The programmer apparently needed a type that had all the features of `CatalogCategory` plus an additional property, `key`, with the type `string`. In TypeScript it's called an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).

Here's a slightly-contrived example:

```
interface CatalogCategory {
   id: number;
   name: string;
}

type CatalogCategoryWithKey = CatalogCategory & { key: string };

function example(param: CatalogCategoryWithKey) {
   const { id, name, key } = param;
   console.log(`${id}, ${name}, ${key}`);
}

const cat: CatalogCategory = { id: 42, name: "Answer" };

example({ ...cat, key: "something" });
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=39#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzHANgewObqR45QCeyA3gLABQy9wAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDctemzicIrAM5gooPAJoBfWrTCkADikLZ8hCMTIB1YGAAWAaQjkAvGgxaCGXSXIAySsgDWFiVJnJ5c2hh2EAQwYBwQZAgADxFVLAgAClU4KBFWTVx7IidDE3NSAEpKQXoECMk3JgAaYVFaz3J5ZGsUtM45IXKQcRwEgDosxIADABIKJnla8ZARCCnkccb5YcK5RRpabsqEDAzbLJ09KyqWZAAWACZa2dFWACIAQR6Ad2h7vwCaGLiExIpkP0gbswA0vMh7r1RCYZB95GsgA)

Comment: One reason I can think of for such a type is if you need something with all the properties of `CatalogCategory` and you're specifying the type of a React component's properties, which may also include `key` (for instance: if you're outputting a list of `CatalogCategory` objects). You don't normally have to create your own type for that, but it's one example where you may want to add `key` to an existing type.

Answer (score 0):

This expression "merges" 2 types into one. When used on types, the `&` operator acts more or less like a `+` would for strings.

It's called [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types).

Alternatively, a new interface could be used as well, it's just a little more verbose:

```
interface CatalogCategoryWithKey extends CatalogCategory {
    key: string;
}
```